# ¿Como pasar parámetros a una función sin ejecutar la función?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo al siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la columna de Acciones están los botones en la cual al hacer clic debe aparecer un menú emergente, para ello tengo hecho lo siguiente:

ver_producto.html:

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-agregar-foto">Agregar Fotos</li>
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-detalles">Detalles</li>
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-modificar">Modificar</li>
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-eliminar">Eliminar</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Productos</h1>
        <div>
            <button class="btn outlined primary">Registrar Producto</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table-productos" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Fotos</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</main>
```

ver_producto.js:

```
const body = document.body;
const menu_item_agregar_fotos = document.getElementById("menu-item-agregar-foto");
const menu_item_detalles = document.getElementById("menu-item-detalles");
const menu_item_modificar = document.getElementById("menu-item-modificar");
const menu_item_eliminar = document.getElementById("menu-item-eliminar");

body.onload = getProductos;

document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 27) {
        hiddenOptions();
    }
});

function onClick(value) {
    hiddenOptions();
    alert(value);
}

function showOptions() {
    const context_menu = document.querySelector(".container-menu");
    context_menu.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hiddenOptions() {
    const context_menu = document.querySelector(".container-menu");
    context_menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function getProductos() {
    const table_productos = document.querySelector(".table-productos > tbody");
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("get", "http://localhost/duralit/app/producto/obtener_productos.php");
    request.onload = () => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            json.forEach((data) => {
                const tr = document.createElement("tr");
            
                const th_codigo = document.createElement("th");
                const td_producto = document.createElement("td");
                const td_descripcion = document.createElement("td");
                const td_total_fotos = document.createElement("td");
                const td_acciones = document.createElement("td");
                const btn_options = document.createElement("button");
                const img_options = document.createElement("img");

                th_codigo.id = "codigo-producto";
                td_total_fotos.id = "total-fotos";
                td_acciones.id = "img-options";
                btn_options.id = "btn-options";
                img_options.src = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5718/5718983.png";
                img_options.width = 15;
                img_options.height = 15;

                th_codigo.textContent = data.codigo_producto;
                td_producto.textContent = data.nombre;
                td_descripcion.textContent = data.descripcion;
                td_total_fotos.textContent = "0";
            
                btn_options.appendChild(img_options);
                btn_options.onclick = showOptions;
                td_acciones.appendChild(btn_options);
                tr.appendChild(th_codigo);
                tr.appendChild(td_producto);
                tr.appendChild(td_descripcion);
                tr.appendChild(td_total_fotos);
                tr.appendChild(td_acciones);

                table_productos.appendChild(tr);

                menu_item_detalles.onclick = onClick("123");
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn("Error: " + error);
        }
    };

    request.send();
}
```

En la clase javascript cuando se crean las filas de la tabla agregue el siguiente código:

> menu_item_detalles.onclick = onClick("123");

Pero cuando recargo la página el mensaje aparece la cantidad de registros que hay en la tabla, es decir, si hay 20 registros, el mensaje aparece 20 veces y al final se carga la tabla, y si a la función le quito el argumento y llamo a la función así:

> menu_item_detalles.onclick = onClick;

recién la tabla se carga completamente.

Pero necesito que la función reciba un parámetro ¿cómo puedo enviarle un parámetro sin que se ejecute la función? la función solo debe ejecutarse cuando hago clic en alguna de las opciones no cuando recargo la pagina.

Comment: Deberías pensar en organizar mejor el código. *la función solo debe ejecutarse cuando hago clic en alguna de las opciones no cuando recargo la pagina*. Pues organiza el código para que eso ocurra.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comentan, la función que tratas de usar para [manejar el evento: `onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) tiene una firma específica, por lo cual, pasar argumentos a la misma no es posible tal como lo intentas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Con `menu_item_detalles.onclick = onClick("123")` llamas la función `onClick` y asignas su resultado a `menu_item_detalles.onclick`.

Con `menu_item_detalles.onclick = onClick` asignas la función `onClick` a `menu_item_detalles.onclick`.

Que yo sepa no puedes guardar los parámetros a pasarle como tal. Sí puedes crear una nueva función, o una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) en la que hagas la llamada a la función original con los parámetros correspondientes.

Así:

```
menu_item_detalles.onclick = () => onClick("123")
```

Por ejemplo, así puedes hacer un botón que abra un alert con un mensaje:

```js
boton = document.getElementById("btn")

// Si es posible, es preferible usar addEventListener
// boton.onclick = () => alert("Hola")
boton.addEventListener("click", () => alert("Hola"))
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click"/>
```